# Attach to Midnight Commander session

Tags: linux, bash, midnight-commander

I found kind of hard but I can't attach to `MC` session.

I tried to find something in tutorials in internet but there is nothing about detached/attached `MC`. I've detached it by... mistake, but there is going important stuff so I can't just kill `PID`.

In top (`top -c`) it looks like that:

```bsh
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
17679 root      20   0  859920 696296   3692 S  43.8 17.9 885:19.76 /usr/bin/mc -P /tmp/mc-root/mc.pwd.17667
```

So I know that it exist but I don't have clue how to attach to that.

Comment: When you say "detatched" what exactly did you do? Do you mean you used some sort of detatch feature inside mc? or do you mean you closed the terminal?

Comment: If the latter you can try installing reptyr and attatching to the process using "reptyr -T 17679"

Comment: I don't know how exactly, if I used mc feature (most probably) or screen feature (mc is going in screen for safety but into screen I'm able to went but in it that mc just gone and it's in background) and I'm only strict to soft already installed at server and I shouldn't (maintain reasons) install anything else

Comment: I don't know what's happening. I clicked several times `Backspace` key in new `mc` instance and I've got my session back.